# What is the simplest way to remove phase angle discontinuities

Tags: python, math

Say I'd like to plot a phase array

```
ph = [1, 40, 80, 179, -173, -150, -90, -40, -3, 3] on an X-Y plot.
```

The jump between [179, -173] is so hideous that I used mod(ph+360, 360) to get rid of it. This however makes [-3, 3] become [357,3].

I know I can have a loop to remove all discontinuities of this sort. But I wonder whether there's a more elegant way.

Comment: Are you willing to have a plot where Y goes from 0 to 370?

Comment: Which language are you using `python` or `C`?

Comment: Python, though I was more looking for a mathematical solution.

Comment: @Beta, I'd like to know your thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into 1-D phase unwrapping. In Matlab there is the [`unwrap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) function and the similar [`numpy.unwrap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) in Python for arguments in radians. In Matlab:

```
ph = [1, 40, 80, 179, -173, -150, -90, -40, -3, 3];
ph2 = unwrap(ph*pi/180)*180/pi
```

which returns:

```
ans =

  Columns 1 through 7

    1.0000   40.0000   80.0000  179.0000  187.0000  210.0000  270.0000

  Columns 8 through 10

  320.0000  357.0000  363.0000
```

If you want to look at the code or if you really need a version specific to degrees, type `edit unwrap` in the command window. Here's simplified version for vector inputs (see `unwrap` for detailed comments for each line):

```
function p = unwrap_deg(p)
m = length(p);
dp = diff(p,1);
dps = mod(dp+180,360)-180;
dps(dps==-180 & dp>0) = 180;
dp_corr = dps-dp;
dp_corr(abs(dp)<180) = 0;
p(2:m) = p(2:m)+cumsum(dp_corr);
```

Then

```
ph = [1, 40, 80, 179, -173, -150, -90, -40, -3, 3];
ph2 = unwrap_deg(ph)
```

which returns

```
ans =

     1    40    80   179   187   210   270   320   357   363
```

Answer (score 1):

You could represent your data as [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles), which are basically a compact way of representing coordinates in three dimensional space plus a rotation. The cool thing with quaternions is that they avoid angle discontinuities.

You can see the advantage of using these [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions), about 1/4 of the way down the page. Your rotation angles are always mapped onto the interval `[-1, 1]` by the operation `q4 = cos(theta / 2)`. This may help you represent your data without discontinuities.

Comment: Sounds like overkill. We don't even know if the wrapped phase angles in question represent 3-D rotations. There's no true discontinuity in 2-D. The types of discontinuities are completely different.

Comment: True. I suppose I just like quaternions and am an advocate for their use. They would definitely add unnecessary complications if all you need is the 2D angles.

Comment: @Engineero, thanks. It sounds like something interesting. I'll definitely read about it.